# How to determine whether a linux kernel is 32bit or 64bit from a running kernel module

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, operating-system, kernel

Here is the deal. I want to write a kernel module which depends on the kernel type (32 or 64 bit).
There are some lines of code which I want to be included in the module if and only if the kernel is 32 bit and some lines of code which should be included iff kernel is 64 bit.

Is there anything like #if LINUX_VERSION_CODE < KERNEL_VERSION(2,6,26) for this case ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check for CONFIG_X86_64 and CONFIG_X86_32 - If the arch is x86. For other architectures there are similiar CONFIG options.

Comment: Since from the question he is making a kernel module and needs a compile-time check this is the best option. Also there are some more options that may be relevant since its not clear if it is restricted to X86 or not `CONFIG_64BIT` springs to mind.

Comment: One also needs to be aware of [`CONFIG_X86_X32`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X32_ABI) these days too.

Comment: Good solution since it depends only on the kernel source tree, which you'll need to compile a module anyway.

Comment: @Steve-o: not for a kernel module. There is no such thing as an X32 kernel. The Linux kernel is either 32 or 64 bit. X32 is userland only and runs on 64 bit kernels.

Comment: @jlliagre interesting thx, is there a remote chance if the module communicates with userspace that it needs to be aware of X32 though?

Answer (score 1):

Check this on terminal

```
$ uname -m
x86_64
```

check a binary file to determine on the system

```
$ file /usr/bin/file
/usr/bin/file: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), for GNU/Linux 2.6.8, dynamically linked (uses shared libs), stripped
```

One certainly can run `32-bit` apps on a `64-bit` system, if the system is `multilib`. But you can look at parts of the system itself to verify that it's `64-bit`. Like this, for example

```
 $file /sbin/init
/sbin/init: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), for GNU/Linux 2.6.16, dynamically linked (uses shared libs), stripped
```

**referenced from**

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/how-to-check-linux-kernel-is-32-bit-or-64-bit-612352/

Comment: This does not sound like a good solution to the problem, also checking binary files is not reliable since you can have 32-bit userspace on a 64-bit kernel.

Answer (score 0):

If using `gcc` you could test for `_LP64` or `__LP64__` to be `#define`'ed as `1`:

> These macros are defined, with value 1, if (and only if) the compilation is for a target where long int and **pointer** both **use 64-bits** and int uses 32-bit.

For `gcc`'s predefined macro please read here: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html